# File append issue for an SFTP producer - Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to append the data to a file which is in SFTP server using Apache Camel SFTP component but data is not appending to the file in SFTP server rather it is creating a new file. I am using this file append in split component. Below is the small snippet used to transfer the data. Any suggestions please?

`<to uri="sftp://{{rue.sftp.username}}@{{rue.sftp.host}}:{{rue.sftp.port}}/{{rdx.FileLocation}}?password={{rue.sftp.password}}&amp;fileName=${exchangeProperty.failedFileName}&amp;fileExist=Append" />`

Comment: was there any file in the folder before you run code?

Comment: No, there is no file in that location, when I run the code, it will create the file based on filename which I provided and when I invoking SFTP component again in the loop, it is creating another file instead of updating the data in the same file. Do I need to add any other property to fix this?

Comment: I guess, ${exchangeProperty.failedFileName}, whatever the file name coming out of this is different for each run in a loop, right

Comment: No, it's the same file name. I logged the headers and can see the same file name but when uploading it to SFTP server, it's uploading data with multiple files(Ex: temp.csv and temp_08-24-21_19-07-41.csv)

Comment: instead of ${exchangeProperty.failedFileName}, can you hard-code the file name and run the code and check once.

Comment: I did checked that too by giving file name as temp.csv, it's creating the new files(temp_08-24-21_19-07-41.csv) as stated in my previous comment. Below is the snippet for the same
`<to uri="sftp://{{rue.sftp.username}}@{{rue.sftp.host}}:{{rue.sftp.port}}/{{rdx.rdxFileFailedRecords}}?password={{rue.sftp.password}}&amp;fileName=temp.csv&amp;fileExist=Append" />`